# Confusion about statistical moments

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, expected-value

Consider some probability density function $p(x)$, the $n$th-moment is given by
$$
\mathbb{E}[x^n]=\int x^np(x)dx.
$$
If one considers $\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_i x_i\right]$, it makes sense$^1$ (?) to
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_i x_i\right] =  \sum_i \int x_i p(x_i)dx_i.
$$
But when it comes to $\mathbb{E}\left[(\sum_i x_i\right)^2]$ things get trickier
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\sum_i x_i\right)^2\right] =?  \sum_{i,j} \int x_i x_j p(?)dx_?,
$$
**what should this expression be like?**

1. Simply beause it gives me the right answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\mathbb E\left(\left(\sum_i x_i\right)^2\right)=\mathbb E\left(\sum_i x_i^2\right)+2\mathbb E\left(\sum_{i>j} x_ix_j\right)=\sum_i\mathbb E\left( x_i^2\right)+2\sum_{i>j}\mathbb E\left( x_ix_j\right)
\\=\sum_i\int x_i^2p(x_i)\,dx_i+2\sum_{i>j}\iint x_ix_jp_{ij}(x_i,x_j)\,dx_i\,dx_j
\\=\sum_i(\sigma_i^2+\mu_i^2)+2\sum_{i>j}(\text{cov}(x_i,x_j)+\mu_i\mu_j).$$

If the rv are independent,

$$\iint x_ix_jp_{ij}(x_i,x_j)\,dx_i\,dx_j=\iint x_ix_jp_i(x_i)p_j(x_j)\,dx_i\,dx_j
\\=\int x_ip_i(x_i)\,dx_i\int x_jp_j(x_j)\,dx_j
$$
giving the expectation
$$\sum_i(\sigma_i^2+\mu_i^2)+2\sum_{i>j}\mu_i\mu_j=\sum_i\sigma_i^2+\left(\sum_i\mu_i\right)^2.$$

If the rv are also identically distributed,

$$n\sigma^2+n^2\mu^2.$$

Comment: So in general, $$\mathbb{E}[\prod_i x_i] = \int \prod_i x_i p(x_i) dx_i,$$  only if $\{x_i\}$ are independent?

Comment: @FriendlyLagrangian: sorry, in the integral I treated the rv as independent, which is not necessarily the case. Now fixed.

Comment: All sorted now, thanks for the input!